# Getting wrong output for my DNA sequence matcher program

Tags: python, cs50, dna-sequence

So I'm making a program that's meant to match a sequence of DNA to a specific person in a "database" (CSV file) by getting the longest repeating substring in a sequence (CS50 pset6, the DNA problem). For example, the string 'AGAT' should return in a certain sequence called 'CTASFDGAGATAGATAGATKLCSAD', an amount of 3 for the string returned (AGATAGATAGAT). While I pass the first 4 test cases I'm meant to pass, other than those few cases, I only get 'No match' in my output. I don't know what I can change to get it working? I've narrowed down my problem to either the
`get_longest_repeating_substr` function or the `matching` function (Both are maybe the problem?). 
**Code I'm using:**

```
# determine to whom a sequence of DNA belongs
import sys
import csv
import re

# main function


def main():
    # check the command-line arguments
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        sys.exit("Usage: python dna.py data.csv sequence.txt")
    else:
        # create file paths to load the files later on
        csv_filename = "dna/"+sys.argv[1]
        seqtxt_filename = "dna/"+sys.argv[2]

        # create 2 lists and string which contains the csv and txt file's contents respectively
        person_dna_list = []
        list_of_STR = load_STR_list(csv_filename)
        dna_string = load_txt(seqtxt_filename)
        load_csv(csv_filename, person_dna_list)

        # get longest repeating substring in string per STR and store them in a dict
        results_list = []
        for i in range(len(list_of_STR)):
            longest_result = get_longest_repeating_substr(dna_string, list_of_STR[i])
            results_list.append(longest_result)

        # match a person to the results_list
        temp_dna_list = person_dna_list
        index = matching(temp_dna_list, results_list)

        # give relevant output
        if index != -1:
            print(person_dna_list[index][0])
        else:
            print('No match')


# loads the csv's contents into a list


def load_csv(csvf, listfordict):
    with open(csvf, "r") as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            listfordict.append(row)
        for i in range(len(listfordict)):
            for j in range(1, len(listfordict[i])):
                listfordict[i][j] = int(listfordict[i][j])


# loads the txt files contents into a string


def load_txt(seqtxt):
    with open(seqtxt, "r") as txt_file:
        data = txt_file.read()
        return data

# loads list of STRs into a list by reading the first line of the csv file


def load_STR_list(csvf):
    with open(csvf, "r") as csv_file:
        string = csv_file.readline()
        values = string.replace('name', '').replace('\n', '')
        outgoing_list = values.split(',')
        del outgoing_list[0]
        return outgoing_list


# gets maximum num of times STR repeats


def get_longest_repeating_substr(dna_str, STR):
    array = re.findall(STR, dna_str)
    return len(array)


# return a match result from the DNA sequence's results


def matching(temp_dna_list, results_list):
    # initialize crucial variables
    person_list = temp_dna_list
    compare_list = results_list
    found_index = -1

    # find a match, if no match is found, respond accordingly
    for j in range(len(person_list)):
        if person_list[j][1:len(person_list)+1] == compare_list:
            found_index = j

    return found_index


main()
```

**Test cases I'm meant to pass:** (I pass the first four after the "exists" case, if I do it manually)
[image]

**large.csv and small.csv**
[image]
[image]

**3.txt and 5.txt (the first and second string respectively**

```
AGAAAGTGATGAGGGAGATAGTTAGGAAAAGGTTAAATTAAATTAAGAAAAATTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCAAGATAGGGAATAATGGAGAAATAAAGAAAGTGGAAAAAGATCAGATCAGATCTTTGGATTAATGGTGTAATAGTTTGGTGATAAAAGAGGTTAAAAAAGTATTAGAAATAAAAGATAAGGAAATGAATGAATGAGGAAGATTAGATTAATTGAATGTTAAAAGTTAA

GCTAAATTTGTTCAGCCAGATGTAGGCTTACAAATCAAGCTGTCCGCTCGGCACGGCCTACACACGTCGTGTAACTACAACAGCTAGTTAATCTGGATATCACCATGACCGAATCATAGATTTCGCCTTAAGGAGCTTTACCATGGCTTGGGATCCAATACTAAGGGCTCGACCTAGGCGAATGAGTTTCAGGTTGGCAATCAGCAACGCTCGCCATCCGGACGACGGCTTACAGTTAGTAGCATAGTACGCGATTTTCGGGAAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCCCGTCAACTCATTCACACCGCATCCTTTCCTGCCACTGTAACTAGTCGACTGGGGAACCTCATCATCCATACTCTCCCACATTATGCCTCCCAACCTTGTTAAGCGTGGCATGCTTGGGATTGCATTGATGCTTCTTGGAGAGGACGCTTTCGTTTTGGAGATTACAGGGATCCAATTTTATCATCGGTTCGACTCCCGTAACGACTTAGCAGTAAGGGTGCTAGTTCCTGGTTAGAATCTTAATAAATCACGTCGCTTGGAGCAAGACAAAGATCGTCGTAATGCCAAGTGCACGACCACCTTCAGACTTGCAGGACCCGTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTCGATAGCTATGCGGTTCAATACAATCTTAACGCAATGCAGCGATGTGGTTTCGTACACTTAGCATAAAACCCCCCACATTAAATCGATGTACCCGCCCTCTTAGACGCCAATTTCAATGCCGAACCTCCGGCGGGTATCTCTGCACTAGGAGAAGTAGCACGTCGCTGTAGCGAACTCCTATCGTGAGATAATTTGTAGAGCTGCTCTTATAATACAATAGCTCAGATGGATTATTCCATGGACATCCCCGTGCGTTGTTTCGAGGATGGTAGGTGGAAATTTTGCCAGACCTCTAGTCTTAAACATGGTTGACGTTATAGGCGCTATCTCTTGCGTCTGGAAGTGTTAATCCGTGAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAACACGCAACTCTGGAGGAGGGCACTGCACTGCAAACTTGCGTAATATCCTTCACCCACACTTGCCTGGCCTCCTTGCTTAAAGCTCTGGCGATGCGATTTTTCGGCCCAGTAGCTGAATAGGTCATGAAATGGGCACCGAACTGGAAAGACCCATATATTCGATACTCACAACTTAATGATAGCGCGATTAAGAGCGACACCAAAAACCAAATTACGTTCACGAACCTTTGAGAGTCAAGGAGACTTAGACCGAATTGAATGATCACTGATGCGCCCGCTGATACTGAGCCTCACCATTAATCGCCGACCAATACGGCGTGTACCGGGCGCGGCCTTGCCGCATAACGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATATCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTACACAGCCCCGTCCTCATTGCTAAGTGCACTGGCAACTGGACCTAAAGATTTTTCGAGTATGGCCCTCGAATCAAGCGCCCACCCAGAAACCTACGAGCCAGTAACCCCAGTAAACAAGCATTAGTGCTATATGCTTGCTGCCCACTAGGACCCTTATGGTTCATACCAGGGTGACGTGTCTTGCGGGCCAAGGATGAACCAGAAGCAAGATCCTTAGATGGACGACTGTCTCATTGCTTAAACTCCACATACCAAAGGGCGCGGTAAACGATAGTTTTAGGTAATGTTAGTCGGATGGTTGTCTGCAGCTACCAATACAGCCTGGCACCCAGGGTCTGAACAATAACGCGTGAGAGCAGCTCTCCCGCGTGTGGTGGATTTGCCGTCTATGAAATTGAGGCTCTTGCAACTATTCGCACTCGGAATGCCCTCATATCTGGTGCCTAGCGGCCTTTGCCCCGTGCCGGTAGGACTAAACTCTACGGATCGTTGACGGATCTCGATGTGGAAGATGGTTATGAAAGATAACAACGCGTGTGCTAATTGATTTAGACAAGTATTGCGGCAGTAAAAGATAATCGGCTGCAGAGTTACGAAAGACTTCCATGCATGGATTCCATTCCTTCTAGTATAGGACCCACTCTGAATACACGTCTTGCGGGCCGATCATCTCCACCGCTGCGGAAGAAAGCAATTAAGAATCTATGCTCATTAAGAGTGCGACTATAATGCGGATCTTACAGTGCTAATGATCAGGACGTCGTCCAAGCAGGCTGCATGCCGAATTTAGCTTACGTCAGGATCAGGCGTTATAGCCTGGGAATCGGACTATGAGGACGCCACGACCTCTGGGAGAAAGCTATATACATTGAGGATCGCGCCATCTTTATGAGACTCAAATGAATCTAGATAGGTAGCATTGCGGACTTGAGTTAGCACATCGGTATTGGAAGGTGAGGGTCCTGCCGCTCGTTCTATGTTCGGTTTATAGTATACAAATAGGTCATCCCGAACGTTGAAGTTAAACTCATGACACGTTGTCGTAATGAAACGGGCCTGTTATTAGGGATACAGACAAAAGGCACAAGCTGGCTTGCACATTAAGGCGCACTAGAGATCCTCACAACCGTTGCCCGCACGGAGGTCGTGTCTAACAGACAGTGAACCAGCCGTATTGGGGTGGATGACCTGAGCTTCTTGGGGCCTGTTGTACACCGCGTGTGGTTCAACTGGTACACATACTACGAATATTCGAAATCATTGTACTGTGCTCTTCGGTGCTACTGACTGTGAGCGAATGCATCCCAATCCCAAACAATGCTTGTGGTAGGAGAATTGAAACTCTCGAAGCCTGGCCCAATGTCATCTACTTTTAACATGTCGGGCCAGGAGTTACGGGCATTGCTTACTTACTTTGCCCCCTTACACCACAGCAGCGCGATTCTTGTTGTAGTAGATTTTATACGACTCGCGAATTAAATGGAACTTGTCTGTCCCATATCGATCGTGTCCATCGTAAGATGAGATTGTAGGAGCATTCGGAAGTCTATGCGGCCCAGGGACTACTACGTTAAATCTGGTCAGACGTGGTTTACAAGGCGTCCCGATCTTCTCAGAACATATGGGAAAGCACTACCGTTCCTTCACGCATACAGTTGTTCGTGCCGAACGAGTAAGCTTGCGACCAGCCCACCCGCTAGGGCTATGCAGCGGGTCATGGCTGGCGCCATACTGTGCGGACAACCCACGCTCTGGCAGAAAGCGTCTTGTGTTTTGTAGTAGCTCCAACGGTTAGACCTTCGATATCTATTCAGAGCGCGAGCGACCACTATTAGACGGCATGTAAACAATGTGTATTTGTTCGGCCCAACCGGTATATGGGTAAGACCGCGAAGGGCCTGCGCGAATACCAGCGTCCAAAAATTCCTCACCCGAGATATGCGGTTAGTACCCCTTGGGTAACGGTCCGCTACGGGTAGCGACGCGAGCCGGCCGCATCGGTTGGAGCCGAGTTGTCGGGCAGGCGAGTAACGTGTGCAATTTGATGGGCCCAAGCCTCCGGCACTATCCACCTCATACATCGACAAAAGCACCAAATATGGGGAAAAGCTGAGCGTCGATATGTACATCTACCCAGGAACCGGCCCGAACATTAGGCGGACGTGAATTTCCGACCTAGGTTCGGCTACATTTCTACGATCCAAGCACACGTGAAGGAGGAGGGGTGTTCCGACCGTAAATGAACGAGGTGCGCAGTGACCCGATGGCGTTTAGCGGATAGCCTTCCTATGCCGGCCTATGCTGTATGGTAGTTGGTTGGTGCCTCCAGAGCCACTGCACCCAATCATAGGGTCTACAGCAGCGTACTTATAAAATTGTACGGGTGACCCATATCCATTACGGGTTGCGACCAGTATAGGAGAGTATAACTGCGTGAACTAATGCGTTATGACGCTTCAGAGTTTGCTCGGGCCCGAGTTCTAGGGCTATAATGTGTTAGGGCGCAAGTATGCCAAGCTAAGATGTGGCGTGCACACTAGGAGTTGTGTTCCTCTGCAAGCAGACACGAGCACTCTGGCAGTAGTTTGACCACACCCGGGTATCACTGCTACTCCATTTCGAACAAGCTATTGGAGCGGACAAAATATGCTACTCAAGAGCATTAGTTATAGGTCTACGAGACAGAAGCAGTTACTGAGTCTGAATATTCGATATAAGTAGGCATGGAGGCGGAGCAAAACAACGTCTGCGATCAATCGTGTTGATGACGTATGGCGACTGGAAGGTAAGGACTATGGCCGGACGGAATGATTCATGTTCTGTTCAAAGCTATATTTCGAAGGGGTATATTAGCGGTCCTACACTTGGTTAGCACCCTCCCCCCTCTGGATCCTGCACTAATTCGAGCTGGCCTCCATCGGTATCAGTCCGGAAGCTCCACTCTCTATCGTAGTCCTAATCAACAGGGTGCCAGTTTGCTCACGTGGAAGTTTGAGGCCCTTTGTGCTCCATAGCCAATCACTAACCATGCACGCGCGACCCACTCTACGTCCAGATCGGCTATAATAGTTGCGCCCGGGACTGGCAGAGTAGACATGTAAGCTAGATAGAGCCCCGACATCGGCCAAGAGATCCTACGCTGCTTCCAGATAATGAGAGACATTCTAGCATTAGACATGCAAGTCGGCAGGGACTCCCCTTATCTAGTAATTTCGATGAATTGGTTTTTCGGCTAGCATCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGACCATGCCGACCTCATCATAGAAGGAATGCTCTAAACTTAGAGTGCTACTAGGAAAACTATTAATCAATGATCGTCCTGCTTACATAGCTGGACGGCGAAAGTTCTTATACTGCGGAGGTTGCTGACGTAGAGTGCGCTGGGTACAGCGGATAAGTTGATCAGGGTGGGGATAGGGTGGCTCACCGTTTATACTCATATAGATTCCTGGCGTCGACGCTGTGACAGGGTCGAGATCGAGGGGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGCGGAGCGGAGGGAAAATTATCACCAGAGGGTAGGGGCTCGCGACATTCTATTCAATGCATTTCAAGCTACTTACGTATTTCGGCACAGTGACTACTGCCTGCGCGGCAGCCGTAAGGTTTCCCGTCAATAGGTGGCACGTATCATTGATGAAAGTGTCAGCTAATCATTCAGGCCTTA
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `data.csv` and `sequence.txt` that raises the error?

Comment: @Pietro I have added some samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of getting the STR repeats

```
# gets maximum num of times STR repeats


def get_longest_repeating_substr(dna_str, STR):
    hits = re.findall(rf'(?:{STR})+', dna_str)
    result = max(hits, key=len)
    length = len(result)//len(STR)
    return length
```

The file paths were wrongly setup:(after correction)

```
    # create file paths to load the files later on
    csv_filename = sys.argv[1]
    seqtxt_filename = sys.argv[2]
```

Remove the else of the argv if statement from the main function and correct the indentation, etc of the rest of the main function's code.